# Token 'x.id' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 11 of the expression [elimina({{x.id}})] starting at [x.id}})]

Tags: angularjs

Getting error :

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'x.id' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 11 of the expression [elimina({{x.id}})] starting at [x.id}})].

This is the code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in lista | filter:cerca | orderBy:option" class="{{x.class}}">
    <td>{{x.nome}}</td>
    <td>{{x.cognome | uppercase}}</td>
    <td>{{x.data | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
    <td><a href ng-click="elimina({{x.id}})">Elimina</a></td>
</tr>
```

If I set up a manual number to `elimina(id)` it works, but with the expression `{{x.id}}` inside the ng-repeat it doesn't.
Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use `{{}}` inside `ng-click`

use like this :

```
<td><a href ng-click="elimina(x.id)">Elimina</a></td>
```